# Continuity of inverse mapping of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any name of a function who is continuous and its inverse function is also continuous?

Comment: a continuous bijection with continuous inverse is called a homeomorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called a *homeomorphism*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Such a function is a homeomorphism. See Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism

Answer (score -1):

It is called a bicontinuous function.

Just look at the first sentence in the wikipedia entry for [continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function).

Comment: Yes and what happens if the function is not many-to-one?

Comment: @Thales I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment.